# Adding noise to a 2D cosine function and doing FFT

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to properly add noise to each cosine function and then take the FFT of the sum of the cosines. I am currently doing it like so:

```
import numpy as np

k = np.linspace(0,4.76*10,2400)
kx,ky = np.meshgrid(k, k)

rx = np.array([0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4])
ry = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])
ry = np.tile(ry,5)

for i in range(0,4):
    a = np.full((8,), 0.5 + 0.1*i)
    rx = np.append(rx, a)

tensx = np.tensordot(rx,kx, axes = 0)
tensy = np.tensordot(ry,ky, axes = 0)
z = (0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*(tensx+tensy)) + np.random.normal(-.1, .1, ky.shape)).sum(axis=0)
```

Here is the FFT in 2D without noise:

[image]

and here is the FFT in 2D with noise:

[image]

I am confused about two things:

1. Why is there a high amplitude at [0,0] with the noise FFT? I change the noise to various ranges and the [0,0] amplitude stays.
2. Shouldnt there be more non-purple areas due to the noise or does everything really cancel out?

Here is the entire code if needed:

```
from scipy.fft import fft2, fftshift
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import window
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq
from skimage.feature import blob_dog, blob_log, blob_doh
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq
from scipy.fft import fft
from scipy.fft import fft2
from scipy.fft import fftn


k = np.linspace(0,4.76*10,2400)
kx,ky = np.meshgrid(k, k)

rx = np.array([0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4])
ry = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])
ry = np.tile(ry,5)

for i in range(0,4):
    a = np.full((8,), 0.5 + 0.1*i)
    rx = np.append(rx, a)

tensx = np.tensordot(rx,kx, axes = 0)
tensy = np.tensordot(ry,ky, axes = 0)
z = (0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*(tensx+tensy)) + np.random.normal(-.1, .1, ky.shape)).sum(axis=0)


wz = z * window('hann', z.shape)
plt.figure(0)
plt.imshow(wz, origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()

zf = np.abs(fftshift(fft2(wz)))[1200:, 1200:]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(0, 1.5), ylim=(0, 1.5))

f = fftfreq(len(k), np.diff(k)[0])
plt.imshow(zf, origin='lower', extent=[0,f[:k.size//2][-1], 0 , f[:k.size//2][-1]])
plt.xlabel('['+r'$\mathrm{\mu}$'+r'm]')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change `np.random.normal(-.1, .1, ky.shape)` to `np.random.normal(0, .1, ky.shape)`